# How can I identify what Fragments are current visible on screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have forked an Android application and wish to change the behavior of a specific fragment. How can I use Android Studio to identify what fragments are currently displayed on-screen so that I can navigate to the correct .java file in the source?

Answer (score 2):

When you add the fragment to your transaction add a tag,

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.container, homeFragment, "HOME_FRAGMENT");
```

After that, to check if fragment is currently displayed is easy :

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HOME_FRAGMENT");
if (homeFragment != null && homeFragment.isVisible()) {
   // do whatever you want :)
}
```

Comment: There are a great many fragments, and I was hoping to view this from a tool within Android Studio rather than having to add a bunch of statements to them all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, You want to check on Android Studio which fragment is displayed on the screen?
If so,you can add Log.d("Fragment",getClass().getName()); on each fragment

Comment: I do want to check which fragment is on-screen. There's no tool to list the active fragment without adding code to each fragment manually?

Answer (score -1):

you can look through the Logcat with your app's package name then usually there are some related calling such as `onActivityDestroyed`, from which you can see which fragment that you need to work on